# in pycharm 18.1 community refactoring is disabled. anybody knows if this is a bug or intentional

Tags: python, pycharm

In previous version 17 of pycharm everything was working fine with refactoring.

I had upgraded to new version 18.1 and it appears they had disabled refactoring function. I had tried to see if enabled in settings to no avail.

Comment: Could you please provide an example? What exactly do you want to refactor?

Comment: once i had picked interpreter refactoring started working. looks like upgrade 2017.2 to 2018.1 did not pick project interpeter or requires reconfirmirmation. once interpeter set all refactoring functions are  enabled.